# How to show number of registered users in Laravel based on usertype?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, admin

i'm trying to display data from the database in the admin dashboard

i used this:

```
            <?php
            use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
            $users = DB::table('users')->count();
            echo $users;
            ?>
```

and i have successfully get the correct data from the database

but what if i want to display a specific data

for example in this user table there is "usertype" that specify if the user is normal user or admin
i want to user the same code above but to display a specific usertype

i tried this:

```
<?php
            use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
            $users = DB::table('users')->count()->WHERE usertype =admin;
            echo $users;
            ?>
```

but it didn't work, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have the wrong syntax. Please read docs carefully...Btw here is the code that you can try

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

```
        $users = DB::table('users')->where('usertype','admin')->count();
        echo $users;
        ?>
```

and for working in the laravel see the usage of Model which will be better for you..

Comment: what a rookie mistake, thank you for the help, i appreciate it

Comment: yes and try to use model instead of DB::query for better enhance

Comment: is it for better security?

Comment: yes from every sides....even changing the database systems